# How to get Tomcat to recognize context.xml?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, context.xml

I'm working on a web application using Tomcat 8 and I've been trying to get a custom session manager working. The problem is that I can't get Tomcat to recognize my `context.xml` file that contains the `<Manager .../>` config.

My `server.xml` looks like this:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">

  <Context path="" docBase="/var/www/" override="true" reloadable="false" />
```

I've tried putting my `context.xml` into `/var/www/META-INF` and in `/var/www/WEB-INF/META-INF`. I've also tried putting my `<Manager .../>` configuration under the Context element in the server.xml shown above, and that does work, but the docs advice against putting things in there.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the /META-INF of your web-app? Where it's supposed to go?

Comment: I thought that by putting it in META-INF in `/var/www` I was putting it into the web-app. Is that not where it should go?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the `<Context .../>` element in server.xml so any context.xml file you include in your application will be ignored.

Comment: But if I don't specify a Context element like I have in the server.xml, then how does Tomcat know where the webapp is when it starts?

Comment: Put the web app in the Host's appBase and let automatic deployment take care of it. Then any context.xml packaged in the web app will be processed.